# display custom category attribute

Tags: magento-1.9

I have created a custom category attribute in my magento installation. It works perfectly on the admin side but I cannot figure out how display it in the front end. I have read and think I need a helper script? here is the code for my attribute.

```
<?php

require_once "app/Mage.php";

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));


$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup;

// change details below:
$attribute  = array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'label'=> 'Front Page CTA Desciption',
    'input' => 'textarea',
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'default' => "",
    'group' => "General Information"
);

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'cta_description', $attribute);

$installer->endSetup(); ?>
```

Comment: you can get $category->getCtaDescription() from category object

Comment: your answer worked perfectly! thank you very much.

Comment: Question though that remains. Where did you get the getCtaDescription because I do not see that in any of my code?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code to display custom category attribute in page (but not in menu navigation):

```
<?php
  $_helper    = $this->helper('catalog/output');
  $_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();

  echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_category->getCtaDescription(), 'cta_description');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question -
`Where did you get the getCtaDescription because I do not see that in any of my code?`

You can find the definition in `lib/Varien/Object.php` class `Varien_Object`. The Varien_Object class is extended by Category model class (its parent, if you check the extends).
So any attribure you create it converts that to automated getter setter method.

```
    /**
     * Set/Get attribute wrapper
     *
     * @param   string $method
     * @param   array $args
     * @return  mixed
     */
    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        switch (substr($method, 0, 3)) {
            case 'get' :
                //Varien_Profiler::start('GETTER: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
                $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method,3));
                $data = $this->getData($key, isset($args[0]) ? $args[0] : null);
                //Varien_Profiler::stop('GETTER: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
                return $data;

            case 'set' :
                //Varien_Profiler::start('SETTER: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
                $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method,3));
                $result = $this->setData($key, isset($args[0]) ? $args[0] : null);
                //Varien_Profiler::stop('SETTER: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
                return $result;

            case 'uns' :
                //Varien_Profiler::start('UNS: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
                $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method,3));
                $result = $this->unsetData($key);
                //Varien_Profiler::stop('UNS: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
                return $result;

            case 'has' :
                //Varien_Profiler::start('HAS: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
                $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method,3));
                //Varien_Profiler::stop('HAS: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
                return isset($this->_data[$key]);
        }
        throw new Varien_Exception("Invalid method ".get_class($this)."::".$method."(".print_r($args,1).")");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get custom attribute value of the category

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(5)->getCtaDescription(); // you can load your category by your category id
```

**Edit**
If you want to get the value in category view page

```
Mage::registry('current_category')->getCtaDescription();
```

Comment: i'm loading the categories dynamically so I cannot target them by id.

Comment: Where you want to show this?

Comment: I wanted this to show within a template page.

Comment: If you want to get the value in category view page?

Comment: I have update my anwser